# A File causes VSCode Intellisense to stop working

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have a python script that, whenever I try to do a while loop in it, VSCode intellisense to completely stop working (not detecting undefined variables, bad expressions etc) or freak out (detect problems where there isn't any, freezing), in all files, until I close the program and reopen it.

This is the script:

```py
import random
from string import ascii_uppercase
from datetime import datetime as dt
from pandas import read_csv
from numpy import arange

#planet_name = input("What's the name of the planet?")

#start_time = dt.now()
error_message = "Variable undefined"

def csv_parser(path):
    a = read_csv(path, header=0, sep=";")
    return a

def rollDice(numDice):
    results = []
    for x in range(numDice):
        results.append(random.choice(range(1,7)))
    return sum(results)

old_results = ""

loop_count = 0
while loop_count < 3:
    letters = ascii_uppercase
    numbers = "0123456789"
    letters_numbers = letters + numbers
    planet_name = f"""{random.choice(letters)}T{random.choice(letters_numbers)}-{random.choice(numbers)}{random.choice(numbers)}{random.choice(numbers)}"""
    
    #STEP 2: World Type (pg 74)
    overall_type_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\1 - Overall Type Table.csv")
    world_type_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\2 - World Type Table.csv")

    overall_type_roll = rollDice(3)
    #print("Ovr Type Roll: " + str(overall_type_roll))

    world_type_roll = rollDice(3)
    #print("World Type Roll" + str(world_type_roll)) 


    world_type = error_message
    rowN = 0
    for x in range(3): #Overall Type Loop
        if overall_type_roll <= overall_type_table.iloc[rowN,0]:
            overall_type = overall_type_table.iloc[rowN,1]
            break
            
        rowN = rowN + 1 

    rowN = 0   
    if overall_type == overall_type_table.iloc[0,1]: #World Type loop for Hostiles
        for x in range(16):
            if world_type_roll <= world_type_table.iloc[rowN,0]:
                world_type = world_type_table.iloc[rowN,1]
                break
            rowN = rowN + 1


    elif overall_type == overall_type_table.iloc[1,1]: #World Type loop for Barrens
        for x in range(16):
            if world_type_roll <= world_type_table.iloc[rowN,0]:
                world_type = world_type_table.iloc[rowN,2]
                break
            rowN = rowN + 1
        
        
    elif overall_type == overall_type_table.iloc[2,1]: #World Type loop for Gardens
        for x in range(16):
            if world_type_roll <= world_type_table.iloc[rowN,0]:
                world_type = world_type_table.iloc[rowN,3]
                break
            rowN = rowN + 1

    overall_type = "Hostile"
    world_type = "Standard (Chthonian)"
    #world_type = "Asteroid Belt"
    #world_type = "Tiny (Ice)"

    #STEP 3: Atmosphere (pg 78)
    #Atmospheric Mass

    atmo_mass_roll = rollDice(3)
    if (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[9,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[5,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[3,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[7,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[0,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[13,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[6,1]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[1,1]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[15,1]):
        atmo_mass = 0

    else:
        atmo_mass = (atmo_mass_roll / 10) + (random.choice(range(-5,5)) / 100)
        
    #Atmospheric Composition
    atmo_comp_roll = rollDice(3)

    if (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[9,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[5,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[3,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[7,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[0,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[13,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[6,1]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[1,1]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[15,1]):
        atmo_comp = "Inexistent"
        
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[1,2]):
        if atmo_comp_roll <= 15:
            atmo_comp = "Nitrogen and Methane (Suffocating and Mildly Toxic)"
        else:
            atmo_comp = "Nitrogen and Methane (Suffocating and Highly Toxic)"
            
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[9,1]):
        atmo_comp = "Nitrogen, Ammonia and Methane (Suffocating, Lethally Toxic and Corrosive)"
        
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[12,2]):
        if atmo_comp_roll <= 12:
            atmo_comp = "Nitrogen and Carbon Dioxide (Suffocating)"
        else:
            atmo_comp = "Nitrogen and Carbon Dioxide (Suffocating and Mildly Toxic)"

    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[11,2]):
        if atmo_comp_roll <= 12:
            atmo_comp = "Nitrogen and Carbon Dioxide (Suffocating)"
        else:
            atmo_comp = "Nitrogen and Carbon Dioxide (Suffocating and Mildly Toxic)"
            
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[13,3]):
        atmo_comp = "Nitrogen and Free Oxygen"

    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[3,1]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[13,1]):
        atmo_comp = "Inexistent"
        
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[11,1]):
        atmo_comp = "Helium Gas, Ammonia and Methane (Suffocating, Lethally Toxic and Corrosive"
        
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[15,2]) or world_type_table.iloc[14,2]:
        atmo_comp = "Helium and Nitrogen Gases (Suffocating and Highly Toxic"
        
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[15,3]):
        atmo_comp = "Nitrogen, Noble Gases and Free Oxygen"

    #Marginal Atmospheres
    marg_atmo_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\4 - Marginal Atmospheres Table.csv")

    marg_atmo_presence_roll = rollDice(3)
    marg_atmo_roll = rollDice(3)

    rowN = 0
    if ("Garden" in world_type) and marg_atmo_presence_roll >= 12:
        for x in range(9):
            if marg_atmo_roll <= marg_atmo_table.iloc[rowN,0]:
                atmo_comp = atmo_comp + marg_atmo_table.iloc[rowN,1]
                break
            rowN = rowN + 1
            


    #STEP 4: Hydrographic Coverage 
    hydrocover_math = error_message
    if (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[9,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[5,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[3,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[7,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[0,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[13,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[6,1]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[1,1]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[15,1]):
        hydrocover_math = 0
        hydrocover = str(0) + "%"
        
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[1,2]):
        hydrocover_math = (rollDice(1) + 2) * 10
        hydrocover = str(hydrocover_math) + "% (Hydrocarbons)"
        
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[9,1]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[11,1]):
        hydrocover_math = (rollDice(2) * 10)
        if hydrocover_math > 100:
            hydrocover_math = 100
        hydrocover = str(hydrocover_math) + "% (Ammonia + Water)"

    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[12,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[15,2]):
        hydrocover_math = (rollDice(2) - 10) * 10
        if hydrocover_math < 0:
            hydrocover_math = 0        
        hydrocover = str(hydrocover_math) + "% (Water; Temporary)"

    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[11,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[13,3]):
        hydrocover_math = (rollDice(2) + 4) * 10
        if hydrocover_math > 100:
            hydrocover_math = 100
        hydrocover = str(hydrocover_math) + "% (Water)"
        
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[14,2]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[15,3]):
        hydrocover_math = (rollDice(2) + 6) * 10
        if hydrocover_math > 100:
            hydrocover_math = 100
        hydrocover = str(hydrocover_math) + "% (Water)"
        
    elif (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[3,1]) or (world_type == world_type_table.iloc[13,1]):
        hydrocover_math = (rollDice(2) - 7) * 10
        if hydrocover_math < 0:
            hydrocover_math = 0
            hydrocover = str(0) + "%"
            
        else:
            hydrocover = str(hydrocover_math) + "% (Water; Temporary)"
        
        if hydrocover_math > 0:
            atmo_comp = "Nitrogen, Water Vapor and Free Oxygen (Suffocating, Lethaly Toxic and Corrosive)"
        
        else:
            atmo_comp = "Carbon Dioxide (Suffocating, Lethaly Toxic and Corrosive)"



    #STEP 5: Climate (pg 83)
    avg_surf_temp_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\5 - Average Surface Temperature Table.csv")
    world_climate_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\6 - World Climate Table.csv")
    temp_factors_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\7 - Temperature Factors Table.csv")

    #Climate Type
    avg_surf_temp_roll = (rollDice(3) - 3) 

    rowN = 0 #Finding average surface temperature
    for x in range(20):
        if world_type == avg_surf_temp_table.iloc[rowN,0]:
            avg_surf_temp = ((avg_surf_temp_roll * avg_surf_temp_table.iloc[rowN,3]) + avg_surf_temp_table.iloc[rowN,1])
            break
        
        rowN = rowN + 1
        
        
    rowN = 0 #Defining world climate
    for x in range(12):
        if avg_surf_temp <= world_climate_table.iloc[rowN,1]:
            world_climate = world_climate_table.iloc[rowN,2]
            break
        
        rowN = rowN + 1

    #Determining Blackbody Temperature
    rowN = 0 
    for x in range(20): #Defining Absorption and Greenhouse factor to calculate blackbody temperature
        if world_type == temp_factors_table.iloc[rowN,0]:
            absorp_factor = temp_factors_table.iloc[rowN,1]
            greenhouse_factor = temp_factors_table.iloc[rowN,2]
            break
        
        elif (("Ocean" in world_type) or ("Garden" in world_type)) and (hydrocover_math <= 20):
            absorp_factor = temp_factors_table.iloc[12,1]
            greenhouse_factor = temp_factors_table.iloc[12,2]
            break
        
        elif (("Ocean" in world_type) or ("Garden" in world_type)) and (hydrocover_math <= 50):
            absorp_factor = temp_factors_table.iloc[13,1]
            greenhouse_factor = temp_factors_table.iloc[13,2]
            break
        
        elif (("Ocean" in world_type) or ("Garden" in world_type)) and (hydrocover_math <= 90):
            absorp_factor = temp_factors_table.iloc[14,1]
            greenhouse_factor = temp_factors_table.iloc[14,2]
            break
        
        elif (("Ocean" in world_type) or ("Garden" in world_type)) and (hydrocover_math <= float("inf")):
            absorp_factor = temp_factors_table.iloc[15,1]
            greenhouse_factor = temp_factors_table.iloc[15,2]
            break
            
        rowN = rowN + 1

    blackbody_correction = absorp_factor * (1 + (atmo_mass * greenhouse_factor))

    blackbody_temp = avg_surf_temp / blackbody_correction



    #STEP 6: World Size (pg 84)
    world_density_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\8 - World Density Table.csv")

    if "Asteroid Belt" not in world_type:
        if ("Sulfur" in world_type) or ("Ice" in world_type) or ("Hadean" in world_type) or ("Ammonia" in world_type):
            core_type = "Icy Core"

        elif ("Rock" in world_type):
            core_type = "Small Iron Core"
            
        else:
            core_type = "Large Iron Core"


        world_density_roll = rollDice(3)
            
        rowN = 0
        for x in range(5):
            if world_density_roll <= world_density_table.iloc[rowN,0]:
                if "Icy" in core_type:
                    world_density_ratio = world_density_table.iloc[rowN,1] + (random.choice(range(-5,5)) / 100)
                    break
                
                elif "Small" in core_type: 
                    world_density_ratio = world_density_table.iloc[rowN,2] + (random.choice(range(-5,5)) / 100)
                    break
                
                elif "Large" in core_type:
                    world_density_ratio = world_density_table.iloc[rowN,3] + (random.choice(range(-5,5)) / 100)
                    break
            
            rowN = rowN + 1


        world_density_cm3 = world_density_ratio * 5.52



        #Diameter and Surface Gravity
        size_constraints_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\9 - Size Constraints Table.csv")

        diameter_roll = rollDice(2) - 2
        min_constraint = "You shouldn't be getting this output."
        max_constraint = "You shouldn't be getting this output."


        if "Large" in world_type:
            min_constraint = size_constraints_table.iloc[0,1]
            max_constraint = size_constraints_table.iloc[0,2]

        elif "Standard" in world_type:
            min_constraint = size_constraints_table.iloc[1,1]
            max_constraint = size_constraints_table.iloc[1,2]

        elif "Small" in world_type:
            min_constraint = size_constraints_table.iloc[2,1]
            max_constraint = size_constraints_table.iloc[2,2]

        elif "Tiny" in world_type:
            min_constraint = size_constraints_table.iloc[3,1]
            max_constraint = size_constraints_table.iloc[3,2]
                

        min_diameter = ((blackbody_temp / world_density_ratio) ** 1/2) * min_constraint
        max_diameter = ((blackbody_temp / world_density_ratio) ** 1/2) * max_constraint

        world_diameter_ratio = (diameter_roll * ((max_diameter - min_diameter)/10)) + min_constraint
        world_diameter_meter = world_diameter_ratio * 6378

        surface_gravity = world_density_ratio * world_diameter_ratio
        gravity_acceleration = surface_gravity * 9.807

        world_mass = world_density_ratio * (world_diameter_ratio ** 3)

    else:
        core_type = "Not Applicable"
        world_density_roll = "Not Applicable"
        world_density_ratio = "Not Applicable"
        world_density_cm3 = "Not Applicable"
        diameter_roll = "Not Applicable"
        min_constraint = "Not Applicable"
        max_constraint = "Not Applicable"
        min_diameter = "Not Applicable"
        max_diameter = "Not Applicable"
        world_diameter_ratio = "Not Applicable"
        world_diameter_meter = "Not Applicable"
        surface_gravity = "Not Applicable"
        gravity_acceleration = "Not Applicable"
        world_mass = "Not Applicable"

    #Determining Atmospheric Pressure
    pressure_factors_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\10 - Pressure Factors Table.csv")
    atmo_pressure_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\3 - Atmospheric Pressure Categories Table.csv")

    if ("Asteroid" in world_type) or ("Tiny" in world_type) or ("Hadean" in world_type):
        atmo_pressure = 0

    elif ("Rock" in world_type) or ("Chthonian" in world_type):
        atmo_pressure = (random.choice(arange(0,0.01,0.001)))

    else:
        rowN = 0
        for x in range(11):
            if world_type in pressure_factors_table.iloc[rowN,0]:
                pressure_factor = pressure_factors_table.iloc[rowN,1]
                break
            rowN = rowN + 1
            
        atmo_pressure = atmo_mass * pressure_factor * surface_gravity
        
    if atmo_pressure == 0:
        atmo_pressure_category = "(Non-Existent)"

    else:
        rowN = 0
        for x in range(7):
            if atmo_pressure <= atmo_pressure_table.iloc[rowN,1]:
                atmo_pressure_category = atmo_pressure_table.iloc[rowN,2]
                break
            rowN = rowN + 1


    #STEP 7: Resources and Habitability
    resources_value_table = csv_parser(R"H:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Tables\11 - Resource Value Table.csv")

    resources_value_roll = rollDice(3)

    rowN = 0
    if "Asteroid" in world_type:
        for x in range(11):
            if resources_value_roll <= resources_value_table.iloc[rowN,0]:
                resources_value_mod = resources_value_table.iloc[rowN,3]
                resources_value_category = resources_value_table.iloc[rowN,2]
                break
            rowN = rowN +1

    else:
        for x in range(11):
            if resources_value_roll <= resources_value_table.iloc[rowN,1]:
                resources_value_mod = resources_value_table.iloc[rowN,3]
                resources_value_category = resources_value_table.iloc[rowN,2]
                break
            rowN = rowN +1

    habitability_mod = 0
    if atmo_pressure <= 0.009:
        habitability_mod = 0
        
    elif "Suffocating" in atmo_comp:
        if ("Toxic" in atmo_comp) and ("Corrosive" in atmo_comp):
            habitability_mod = habitability_mod - 2
        
        elif ("Toxic" in atmo_comp):
            habitability_mod = habitability_mod - 1
        
        else:
            habitability_mod = habitability_mod + 0 

    elif ("Frozen" in world_climate) or ("Very" in world_climate) or ("Infernal" in world_climate):
        habitability_mod = habitability_mod + 0 

    elif ("Cold" in world_climate) or ("Hot" in world_climate):
        habitability_mod = habitability_mod +1

    elif ("Chilly" in world_climate) or ("Coll" in world_climate) or ("Normal" in world_climate) or ("Warm" in world_climate) or ("Tropical" in world_climate):
        habitability_mod = habitability_mod +2

    if ("Very Thin" in atmo_pressure_category) or ("Very Dense" in atmo_pressure_category) or ("Superdense" in atmo_pressure_category):
        habitability_mod = habitability_mod + 1

    elif ("Thin" in atmo_pressure_category):
        habitability_mod = habitability_mod + 2
        
    elif ("Standard" in atmo_pressure_category) or ("Dense" in atmo_pressure_category):
        habitability_mod = habitability_mod + 3


    if marg_atmo_presence_roll <= 11:
        habitability_mod = habitability_mod + 1

    if ("Water" in hydrocover) and not ("Ammonia" in hydrocover) and not ("Temporary" in hydrocover):
        if hydrocover_math <= 59:
            habitability_mod = habitability_mod + 1

        elif hydrocover_math <= 90:
            habitability_mod = habitability_mod + 2
            
        elif hydrocover_math <= 99:
            habitability_mod = habitability_mod + 1

        else :
            habitability_mod = habitability_mod + 0

    affinity_score = habitability_mod + resources_value_mod

    results = f"""==================================================================

    Name: {planet_name}

    Overall Type Roll: {overall_type_roll} World Type Roll:{world_type_roll}
    World  Type: {world_type} ({overall_type}),


    Atmospheric Mass Roll: {atmo_mass_roll}, Atmospheric Comp Roll: {atmo_comp_roll},
    Marginal Atmosphere Roll: {marg_atmo_presence_roll} Marginal Atmo. Table Roll: {marg_atmo_roll}

    Atmospheric Mass: {atmo_mass}, Atmospheric Composition: {atmo_comp},
    Atmospheric Pressure: {atmo_pressure} ({atmo_pressure_category})


    Hydrographic Math: {hydrocover_math} Hydrographic Cover: {hydrocover}


    Avg. Surf. Temp. Roll: {avg_surf_temp_roll}

    Avg Surf Temp: {avg_surf_temp}, World Climate: {world_climate}

    Absorption Factor: {absorp_factor}, Greenhouse Factor: {greenhouse_factor},
    Blackbody Correction: {blackbody_correction}, Blackbody Temperature: {blackbody_temp}


    World Density Roll: {world_density_roll}
    Core Type: {core_type}, World Density: {world_density_ratio} Earth's or {world_density_cm3}g/cm3

    Diameter Roll: {diameter_roll}
    Min. Constraint: {min_constraint}, Max. Constrain: {max_constraint},
    Min. Diameter: {min_diameter}, Max. Diameter: {max_diameter},
    Diameter : {world_diameter_ratio} Earth's or {world_diameter_meter}m,
    Surface Gravity: {surface_gravity}Gs or {gravity_acceleration} m/s2
    World's Mass: {world_mass}


    Resources Value Roll: {resources_value_roll}
    Resources Value Mod: {resources_value_mod}, Resources Value Category: {resources_value_category}

    Habitability Score: {habitability_mod}, Affinity Score: {affinity_score}"""
    
    new_results = old_results + results
    old_results = new_results
    loop_count = loop_count + 1

results = old_results


with open("GURPS Space/output.txt","a") as f:
    write_data = f.write(results)
```

I've already tried uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode as well as Python and it still happens. Any idea why?

EDIT

Python Log from the Output Window:

```
> pyenv root
> conda --version
> python3.7 -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3.6 -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3 -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python2 -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -3.7 -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -3.6 -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -3 -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> py -2 -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> ~\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> conda info --json
Error 2021-08-17 14:00:03: Detection of Python Interpreter for Command py and args -3.7 failed as file Python 3.7 not found!

 -3.9-64 does not exist
Error 2021-08-17 14:00:03: Detection of Python Interpreter for Command py and args -3.6 failed as file Python 3.6 not found!

 -3.9-64 does not exist
Error 2021-08-17 14:00:03: Detection of Python Interpreter for Command py and args -2 failed as file Python 2 not found!

 -3.9-64 does not exist
Starting Pylance language server.
> conda --version
```

Python Language Server Log from the Output window:

```
Background analysis message: setFileOpened
Background analysis message: getDiagnosticsForRange
Background analysis message: getDiagnosticsForRange
[FG] parsing: h:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Planet Generator.py (86ms)
[FG] binding: h:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Planet Generator.py (9ms)
Background analysis message: getSemanticTokens full
[BG(1)] getSemanticTokens full at h:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Planet Generator.py ...
[BG(1)]   parsing: h:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Planet Generator.py (79ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: h:\01 Libraries\Documents\Tosh0kan Studios\Coding\GURPS Space\Planet Generator.py (9ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\random.pyi [fs read 0ms] (11ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\random.pyi (3ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\string.pyi [fs read 0ms] (5ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\string.pyi (1ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\__init__.pyi [fs read 1ms] (13ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\__init__.pyi (2ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\io\api.pyi [fs read 0ms] (36ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\io\api.pyi (0ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\io\parsers.pyi [fs read 0ms] (65ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\io\parsers.pyi (4ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\_typing.pyi [fs read 0ms] (41ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\_typing.pyi (2ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\os\__init__.pyi [fs read 1ms] (51ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\os\__init__.pyi (9ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\abc.pyi [fs read 0ms] (4ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\abc.pyi (1ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\io.pyi [fs read 1ms] (5ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\io.pyi (3ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\mmap.pyi [fs read 1ms] (4ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\mmap.pyi (1ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\datetime.pyi [fs read 1ms] (16ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\datetime.pyi (18ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\frame.pyi [fs read 2ms] (93ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\frame.pyi (47ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\generic.pyi [fs read 1ms] (23ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\generic.pyi (4ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\base.pyi [fs read 0ms] (4ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\base.pyi (1ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\accessor.pyi [fs read 1ms] (1ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\accessor.pyi (0ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\indexing.pyi [fs read 0ms] (2ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\bundled\stubs\pandas\core\indexing.pyi (1ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\collections\__init__.pyi [fs read 1ms] (6ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\collections\__init__.pyi ...
[BG(1)]     parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\_collections_abc.pyi [fs read 0ms] (1ms)
[BG(1)]     binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\_collections_abc.pyi (0ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\collections\__init__.pyi (11ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\collections\abc.pyi [fs read 1ms] (1ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.vscode-pylance-2021.8.1\dist\typeshed-fallback\stdlib\collections\abc.pyi (0ms)
[BG(1)]   parsing: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.pyi [fs read 2ms] (128ms)
[BG(1)]   binding: c:\Users\Tosh0kan\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.pyi (37ms)
```

I'm using Python 3.9.6.

[GIF of it working just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l6gjT.gif)

[GIF of the issue happening when adding the while keyword](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YzgOV.gif)

Comment: Does it work again if you replace everything with some trivial code? What happens if you run the code in an interpreter directly (without IDE)?

Comment: @KlausD. The code isn't the problem, it runs fine, even straight from VSCode. The problem is the IDE. If I take out the `while` keyword and reload VSCode, then intellisense starts working again. I did some further testing and what appears to be happening is that this code, with the while loop, makes intellisense get really slow, to the point of freezing.

Comment: Please reduce your code to the minimum required to reproduce the problem!

Comment: @AnFa I can't reproduce the issue, Could you paste the log of `Python` and `Python Language Server` channels in the `OUTPUT` panel? And have you tried to switch the `Language Server`?

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Added the logs plus two gifs, one with intellisense working just fine, and one with it having stopped working after writing the `while` keyword. Yeah, I've tried switching the language server too all available. Pylance, Jedi, etc. It happens in all of them.

Comment: @KlausD. This is the minimum. Any less, and intellisense doesn't freeze, but rather just takes A REALLY LONG TIME to work.

Comment: @AnFa Your code is a little complex, if you annotate the lines from `425` to `498`, you will find the Intellisense with good performance. `Pylance` needs to improve its performance and arithmetic. I submit an issue on the Github, you can refer to it [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/17018)

Comment: @Steven-MSFT Oh, so it was you. I did it as well.